# Javascript Extend NPObject (Google Earth Plugin API)

Tags: javascript, flash, inheritance, google-earth-plugin

I'm trying to extend `KmlPlacemark` in the [Google Earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_placemark.html). Google uses factory methods to create the objects so I can't do something like this:

```
    KmlPlacemark.prototype.foo = function () { /* ... */ }
```

I tried to simply add methods to each of the objects after they were created

```
    function foo () { /* ... */ }
    placemarkObj.foo = foo;
```

but it throws

```
Error: Trying to add unsupported property on NPObject!
```

I ended up just making a wrapper for it, but I'd still want to know if there's any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure, but it looks like you're trying to extend objects that exist inside the browser plugin, which isn't possible - although these objects can be accessed in JavaScript, their implementation is in native code inside the NPAPI plugin.

Comment: but I figured that the flash object would have a javascript wrapper and that's what I'd be extending.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'JavaScript wrapper' - a plugin object already has a JavaScript interface which can't be extended. But if you mean that the flash object has an additional JavaScript layer that wraps the 'raw' JS interface from the plugin, then yes, it would be technically possible to extend this. But from the 'unspported property on NPObect' error that you're seeing it looks like this is not the case